# Run it though / run it thought?

Tags: meaning

I came across the following dialogue in an American TV show, called Younger. Firstly I figured there was an error typing which the correct one should be `run it through` instead of `run it though` as I've never seen `run it though`. I wish to get some clarification if I guess wrongly. Thanks.

[A is a director of publising house and B is an assistant of A]

> A: Let me ask you a question. Do you think I should change my profile
>   photo (Tweeter)? Maybe do one with the Leiber (a made to order bag)?
>
> B: Uh, absolutely.
>
> A: Would you mind taking a few photos?
>
> B: Sure.
>
> A: Oh, no, not with that (B is taking out her cellphone from her
>   pocket). Use this (A is taking out her camera from drawer). And **run it
>   though** one of those fancy Instagram filters.

Also, There are few sentences for run though  :

> 1. Your most fun pokemon to **run though** levels with
> 2. Trying to **run though** a bad diet
> 3. Can Ted Cruz **run though** he was born In Canada?

Comment: It's "through". ... Where did you find the written text?

Comment: @Catija Hi, here's the link http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=younger-2015&episode=s01e03

Comment: It's just an error in the text. It's definitely "run it through".

Comment: Sure!  I'd definitely wait to see if anyone has any other ideas but I'm pretty sure it's just a typo.

Comment: @Catija I'm looking forward to that!

Comment: However, example 3 about Ted Cruz probably is correct: "Can Ted Cruz run *even though* he was born in Canada?" Perhaps it's speculating about a US Presidential campaign.

Comment: I edited your title. It said "thought"!  See how easy it is to make such typos?

Comment: One might say, eg, "I guess I should run it, though I think it's a bad idea."  But most if not all of the above samples are unintentionally misspellings -- spell check never bats an eyelash, and proofreading is dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ABABA example, it should definitely have been *through*. However, in some spoken dialect, the R is elided.  I remember a TV commercial wherein some sports personality extolled Lipton's "Flow-Thoo" teabags.  But this does not sound like "though".

As for your 1, 2, 3 examples:

- ## 1: ...to run though levels...

  Should be "run **through** levels..."
- ## 2:  ...run though a bad diet...

  Should be "run **through** a bad diet..."
- ## 3 Can Ted Cruz run though he was born in Canada?

  This is correct. The meaning is ...run **(, even)** though he was born in Canada?

Comment: @ Brian Hitchcock  Hi, actually I noticed the typo **run though** was from a script, not hearing from that TV show. I couldn't hear clearly from TV show whether **though** or **through** because A was speaking too fast for me.